# Is there a way to make a log and exclude that log from further runs of the batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a ripper that downloads gifs, webms, jpg, mp4 and png files from websites like reddit and such.

I have around 25,000 files and 1,500 subfolders.

Currently, my "raw" folder is like mixed this

```
└───UNSORTED
    └───RAW
        ├───reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog
        │   ├───funcatdog.jpg
        │   ├───fundogcat.png
        │   ├───funnycatswithdog_983j331_cutecattries-to_.gif
        │   ├───and 500 more
        ├───reddit_sub_funnydogs
        │   ├───randomcutedog.jpg
        │   ├───randomdogs.png
        │   ├───dograndomfun.webm
        │   ├───and 500 more
```

You get the point.

Now, I have a batch that filters/sort like this

```
└───Sorted
       ├───GIF FOLDER
       │    ├───reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog
       │    │   ├───funnycatswithdog_983j331_cutecattries-to_.gif
       │    │   └───and 100 more
       │    ├───reddit_sub_funnydogs
       │    │   ├───funnydogs_fdsljdsd9s_kiotdawg_123.gif
       │    │   └───and 100 more
       │    ├───reddit_sub_imoutofrandomnames
       │    │   ├───imoutofrandomnames_92382j38du8yu_socute.gif
       │    │   ├───and 100 more
       │    └───reddit_sub_randommemes
       │        ├───randommemes_023093x23_uploadedtitle.gif
       │        └───and 100 more
       ├───JPG
       │    ├───reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog
       │    │   ├───reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog_983j331_cuteries-to_eatdog.JPG
       │    │   └───and 100 more
       │    ├───reddit_sub_funnydogs
       │    │   ├───reddit_sub_funnydogs_fdsljdsd9s_kiotdawg_123.JPG
       │    │   └───and 100 more
       │    ├───reddit_sub_imoutofrandomnames
       │    │   ├───imoutofrandomnames_92382j38du8yu_socute.JPG
       │    │   └───and 100 more
       │    ├───reddit_sub_randommemes
       │    │   ├───randommemes_023093x23_uploadedtitle.JPG
       │    │   └───and 100 more
```

QUESTION 1: MAKE A LOG AND EXCLUDE IT

The thing is, I want to only TRY to copy if the file was never processed by the batch file. The log exclusion is only what I'm seeing as for a solution right now but anything is welcome.

QUESTION 2: CHECK TYPE AND MOVE ACCORDINGLY

I Also wanted to know if I can clean the code a little bit to make it better.
I think right now it scans every file 5 times for 5 different types and then move them.

Is there a way to do it only once? Check type, if gif moveto gif if jpg moveto jpg etc.

This is what I have so far. ( no logging or anything because I'm not sure of the format or what I need to log properly)

```
Echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set RAW=D:\RIP\RAW
set GIF=D:\RIP\OneDrive\Sek\GIF
set PNG=D:\RIP\OneDrive\Sek\png
set MP4=D:\RIP\OneDrive\Sek\MP4
set JPG=D:\RIP\OneDrive\Sek\JPG
set WEBM=D:\RIP\webm
cd d:
Cd %RAW%
REM FOR ALL FOLDERS, DO GET IN
for /D %%u in (*) do (
   cd "%%u"
REM ONCE IN, FOR ALL THE FILES IN THE FOLDER, CHECK IF GIF, THEN DO
     for /r %%p in (*.gif) do (
echo n|xcopy  /C /i  "%%p" "%GIF%\%%u\%%~nxp*"
)
REM ONCE IN, FOR ALL THE FILES IN THE FOLDER, CHECK IF JPG, THEN DO
     for /r %%p in (*.JPG) do (
echo n|xcopy  /C /i  "%%p" "%JPG%\%%u\%%~nxp*"
)
REM ONCE IN, FOR ALL THE FILES IN THE FOLDER, CHECK IF MP4, THEN DO
     for /r %%p in (*.MP4) do (
echo n|xcopy  /C /i  "%%p" "%MP4%\%%u\%%~nxp*"

)
REM ONCE IN, FOR ALL THE FILES IN THE FOLDER, CHECK IF WEBM, THEN DO
     for /r %%p in (*.WEBM) do (
echo n|xcopy  /C /i  "%%p" "%WEBM%\%%u\%%~nxp*"

)
REM ONCE IN, FOR ALL THE FILES IN THE FOLDER, CHECK IF PNG, THEN DO
     for /r %%p in (*.PNG) do (
echo n|xcopy  /C /i  "%%p" "%PNG%\%%u\%%~nxp*"

)

    rem Go back one level up to %RAW% to process next %%u
     cd ..
)
```

I tried this:

```
 for /r %%p in (*) do (
if  %%~xp == .GIF (
echo n|xcopy /C /i  "%%p" "%GIF%\%%u\%%~nxp*" 
)
 for /r %%p in (*) do (
if  %%~xp == .JPG (
echo n|xcopy /C /i  "%%p" "%GIF%\%%u\%%~nxp*" 
)
```

but it only copies the same files in all the directories like this:

```
└───Sorted
       ├───GIF FOLDER
       │    ├───reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog
       │    │   ├───funnycatswithdog_983j331_cutecattries-to_.gif
       │    │   ├───and 100 more
       │    ├───reddit_sub_funnydogs
       │    │   ├───funnycatswithdog_983j331_cutecattries-to_.gif
       │    │   ├───and 100 more
       │    ├───reddit_sub_imoutofrandomnames
       │    │   ├───funnycatswithdog_983j331_cutecattries-to_.gif
       ├───JPG FOLDER
       │    ├───reddit_sub_funnycatswithdog
       │    │   ├───funnycatswithdog_983j331_cutecattries-to_.JPG
       │    │   ├───and 100 more
       │    ├───reddit_sub_funnydogs
       │    │   ├───funnycatswithdog_983j331_cutecattries-to_.JPG
       │    │   ├───and 100 more
       │    ├───reddit_sub_imoutofrandomnames
       │    │   ├───funnycatswithdog_983j331_cutecattries-to_.JPG
```

I expect:

1. A WAY TO ONLY TRY/COPY ONCE PER UNIQUE FILE NO MATTER HOW MANY TIMES I RUN THE BATCH
2. A FASTER WAY TO SORT THEM BECAUSE THIS IS REALLY SLOW.

Comment: Regarding the first question - you could make a some kind of index file with unique hashes (or something like this) for every file and check new files against this index.
For a second question I'd suggest you to use a file extension as a name of a destination folder.

Comment: This question is too broad.

Comment: I would need help with that... Also Gerhard what do you mean? Can you help me narrow it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds a bit like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. If I were you I would step back and rethink the whole approach.

Instead of implementing a logging feature to exclude already copied items, let us analyse what makes your script slow. There are some reasons and respective countermeasures:

- You are using pipes in every loop just to confirm the `Overwrite ... (Yes/No/All)?` prompt; pipes create new `cmd` instances for either side, which takes some time. You could avoid them by checking whether or not the target file already exists, using `if exist "<target>" copy "<source>" "<target>"`; or, even better, you could let `xcopy` check whether the source file has been changed since last copying, by using `xcopy /D /Y "<source>" "<target>"`.
- You are iterating over the source directory tree multiple times, once per each file extension. You could however establish a single loop and use the found file extension to decide where to copy the file.

So here is a possible solution (without a logging feature), which should be noticeably faster than your approach -- see all the remarks (`rem`) that explain how it works:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=UNSORTED\RAW" & rem // (this path must not contain `=`, `!` or `^`)
set "_TARGET=SORTED"       & rem // (this path may contain all valid characters)
rem /* Define a pseudo-array with file extensions as indexes, including the preceding `.`,
rem    and directory names as values; this allows to define the same directory for several
rem    file extensions: */
set "$DIRS[.gif]=GIF"
set "$DIRS[.jpeg]=JPG"
set "$DIRS[.jpg]=JPG"
set "$DIRS[.mp4]=MP4"
set "$DIRS[.png]=PNG"
set "$DIRS[.webm]=WEBM"

rem // Use `for` loop that iterates once to resolve target path:
for /D %%D in ("%_TARGET%") do set "ROOT=%%~fD"
rem // Change into source directory:
pushd "%_SOURCE%" && (
    rem // Use `for` loop that iterates once to resolve the source path:
    for /D %%D in (".") do (
        rem // Build list of file patterns that matches all the specified file extensions:
        set "EXTS="
        for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%X in ('set $DIRS[') do call set "EXTS=%%EXTS%% *%%X"
        rem // Find matching files in the source directory tree and iterate through them:
        for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /S /A:-D %%EXTS%%') do (
            rem // Store the path of the currently iterated file:
            set "FILE=%%F"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem /* Build the destination file path by concatenating the resolved target
            rem    directory, the directory namd associated with the current file
            rem    extension and the file path relative to the source directory (which
            rem    is the full file path with the resolved source path removed): */
            set "DEST=!ROOT!\!$DIRS[%%~xF]!\!FILE:*%%~fD\=!"
            rem // Create destination directory, suppress error message if already done:
            2> nul md "!DEST!\.."
            rem // Copy the current file to the target location, except when already done:
            if exist "!DEST!" (
                > nul xcopy /Y /D "!FILE!" "!DEST!"
            ) else (
                > nul copy "!FILE!" "!DEST!"
            )
            endlocal
        )
    )
    rem // Return from source directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: I thought my goal was pretty clear, but I guess it wasn't.
Thanks alot for your time and effort.